# Mathematica symbols not showing

Tags: display

Mathematica displays squares like □ in place of symbols such as slash

/

and right arrow

->

so for example if I write a/b it displays a □ b. Rebooting doesn't seem to help here.

Operating system: Windows 10

Comment: Contacting Wolfram Support might be more effective.

Comment: Did you check what the settings of your keyboard are?

Comment: I agree with MarcoB. Is it possible that your Crtl key is stuck? I produces those 'boxes' as well for special formatting. Does a□b evaluate to a/b?

Comment: @Alex Mathematica displays a□b in place of a/b, but it "knows" that it's a fraction, so it should be a problem of display. For example if I write 1□2+1□2 I get 1. Also, boxes are displayed in the settings as well...